# Environment Map renders wrong

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, image

[image: Glitched Environment Map]

When I'm on Solid view, I can see the environment map. However when I render I get this glitch with my image. I'm in Perspective view, I removed transparency, the image is showing until I render. Why? I adjusted my clipping at 100ft, so I know its not that. Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: I dont understand your question, are you trying to have a transparent background but still use the lighting from the HDRI? if So just go to render tab > Film > uncheck transparency. Can you clarify what the problem is?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I'm trying to have my environment map show up in my render but its rendering a glitched image.

Comment: if you can upload your blend file I can take a look its to hard to tell by just that screen shot.

Comment: Are you referring to the small piece of sky showing through the gap in the roof? It’s really hard to tell what’s going on from that. Perhaps try and isolate the problem by removing everything that isn’t relevant, leaving just the environment map. Perhaps that will then give some clues as to how it’s distorted. You could also provide your HDR image as it could be a problem with that.